# Delete element with specific value from array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this:

```
  nominees: Array<{ id: number,  title: string, company: string, category: string }>;
```

I want to delete based on id, e.g. if the given id is 10, then I want to delete the element with the id of 10

I've been looking at splice, but honestly I'm really having a hard time. I'm quite new to Typescript

Comment: _splice()_ is the way to go. What is your problem with it?

Comment: Can you show us the `splice` code that isn't working?

Comment: Well I honestly thought something like this would've worked `this.nominees.splice(id);`. Apparently it don't be like that. I'm looking for the similar function in java `removeIf(...)`. Thought it was similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use splice, you can use filter as below:

```
let result = nominees.filter(n => n.id !== 10);
```

Comment: This would create a new Array, which may not be bad - but it could.

Comment: What about doing it in place ? 
`nominees = nominees.filter(n => n.id !== 10);`

Comment: Although it doesn't technically delete it, it gives me what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincenzo Even then you would create a copy, which you afterwards assign to _nominees_ . But as it seems this works for the thread opener.